# Help with CountMeIn: add 1 to UILabel2 if UILabel1 value is equal to UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Im an absolute beginner and not English speacking..., I'm trying to play and modify the code of CountMeIn that you can find  on http://appsamuck.com/day5.html.
I've implemented more counters, (score1, score2, set1, set2) and a field for "race to:"
what I would like to:

"race to" can be set to any value; i would like that when score1 is equal or more (+=) than "race to" it reset score1 and score2, and add 1 to set1. Then the same for score2...
here is my code:

MainView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MainView : UIView {
    IBOutlet UILabel *scorer;
    IBOutlet UILabel *seter;
    IBOutlet UILabel *scorer1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *seter1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *racer; // "race  to"
}

- (IBAction)doneButtonOnKeyboardPressed: (id)sender;
- (IBAction)addUnit;
- (IBAction)subtractUnit;
- (IBAction)addUnit2;
- (IBAction)subtractUnit2;
- (IBAction)addUnit3;
- (IBAction)subtractUnit3;
- (IBAction)addUnit4;
- (IBAction)subtractUnit4;
- (IBAction??)countset; // ->?
- (IBAction??)countset1; // ->?
@end
```

MainView.m

```
#import "MainView.h"

    @implementation MainView

    int score = 00;
    int set = 00;
    int score1 = 00;
    int set1 = 00;
    int race = 00;

    -(void)awakeFromNib; {

        scorer.text = @"00";
        seter.text = @"00";
        scorer1.text = @"00";
        seter1.text = @"00";
        racer.text = @"00";

    }

    - (IBAction)addUnit {

        if(score >= 99) return;

        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", ++score];
        scorer.text = numValue;
        [numValue release];


        if(scorer.text == racer.text) return;

        NSString *numValue1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", ++set];
        seter.text = numValue1;
        [numValue1 release];
    }

    - (IBAction)subtractUnit {

        if(score <= 00) return;

        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", --score];
        scorer.text = numValue;
        [numValue release]; 
    }

    - (IBAction)addUnit2 {

        if(set >= 99) return;

        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", ++set];
        seter.text = numValue;
        [numValue release];
    }

    - (IBAction)subtractUnit2 {

        if(set <= 00) return;

        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", --set];
        seter.text = numValue;
        [numValue release]; 
    }

    - (IBAction)addUnit3 {

        if(score1 >= 99) return;

        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", ++score1];
        scorer1.text = numValue;
        [numValue release];

    }

    - (IBAction)subtractUnit3 {

        if(score1 <= 00) return;

        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", --score1];
        scorer1.text = numValue;
        [numValue release]; 
    }

    - (IBAction)addUnit4 {

        if(set1 >= 99) return;

        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", ++set1];
        seter1.text = numValue;
        [numValue release];

    }

    - (IBAction)subtractUnit4 {

        if(set1 <= 00) return;

        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", --set1];
        seter1.text = numValue;
        [numValue release]; 
    }


    - (IBAction)countset{ // I guess its no IBAction...

        if(scorer.text += racer.text add 1 to setter.text  // ->? i can't figure out...
```

Can someone help me please? 
There is for sure another way to write this with less code, but Ill find out later, I'm glad  that its working so far.
Thanks for any help, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question then here is a solution:

```
- (IBAction)countset
{
    // compare values
    if ([scorer.text intValue] >= [racer.text intValue])
    {
        // add 1
        setter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", [setter.text intValue] + 1];
        // reset values
        score1.text = @"";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't had the time to try yet, I know Ill have some trouble because "score" is a UILabel and "Raceto" is a UITextField...

Comment: No its not working properly, it works for the first set, but there are  some things missing to reset properly the values. "score" come back to 00 but then each new point add 1 set, it works if I manually come back to 00 subtracting values. Also "set" can't be changed properly, if for example i want to subtract one, I first have to add one before it works otherwise nothing happen.

Comment: No,no. My code work as you asked. Now you are asking to write full program to you. I only show you the right way to realize your ideas. I think you should close your question by accepting answer

Comment: oh, ok, Im sorry, Im too beginner sorry, I just don't realize, and of course I accept your answer, and will try to find out what Im doing wrong. Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 0):

so i did test and make adjustment, but its not fully working yet;

'countset' should not be an action since it had to check every time the score change, so the best way is to add it to the action 'addUnit':

```
    - (IBAction)addUnit {


    if(score >= 99) return;

    NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", ++score];
    scorer.text = numValue;
    [numValue release];

// compare values
if ([scorer.text intValue] >= [racer1.text intValue])
{
    // add 1
    seter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", [seter.text intValue] + 1];
    // reset values
    scorer.text = @"00";
}
```

this is working, for the first set, but then I guess there is something missing, a release probably, 
Now it works, but after the first set is scored, the score is reset, but it add one set on every new point...
Also, if there was a mistake I can't subtract unit to the set, I first have to add one before I can subtract...

hope you understand, and sorry if I shouldn't answer my own question.

Comment: There is no problem with you answering your own question.

Comment: You can answer your own question, *if you are answering it*.  If your answer is actually a **continuation or addition to the original question** then you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7295215/edit) the *question* and add the new information there.  Not sure which this is; it seems like you are asking another question here.  If you have another question, please ask it in a new question.  Thanks.